# Do I need a visa to transit through South Korea? Vietnamese passport, depart from Taipei

Tags: visas, transit, south-korea, vietnamese-citizens

I am Vietnamese and living in Taiwan. I would like to check if I could enter Korea without a visa as transit program. I got a physical Japan visa.

> 3. Transit tourists bound for another country Eligible countries:
>
> Applicable to all countries (except for Cuba, Macedonia, Syria, Sudan
>   and Iran) that are not granted visa-free entry into Korea.
>
> Applicable to…:
>   - Those with a visa* or a re-entry permit for follwing any 5 countries: U.S., Japan, Canada, Australia, or New Zealand. *except
>   those who hold Group travel visa to Japan
>
> - Those traveling FROM or TO any one of the five countries mentioned above, whose final destination is not Korea.
>
> Requirements
>
> Must have a confirmed onward flight ticket for departure within 30
>   days after entering Korea, in addition to having no record of criminal
>   offence in the five countries mentioned above.

[Here](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/ca-vancouver-en/brd/m_4542/view.do?seq=615041&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&srchTp=&multi_itm_seq=0&itm_seq_1=0&itm_seq_2=0&company_cd=&company_nm=&page=1) is the reference link